# Doing OCR to identify text written on trucks/cars or other vehicles

Tags: computer-vision, ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract

I am new to the world of Computer Vision.

I am trying to use Tesseract to detect numbers written on the side of trucks.

[image: Image of a truck taken from Wikipedia]

So for this example, I would like to see CMA CGM as the output.

I fed this image to Tesseract via command line

```
tesseract image.JPG out -psm 6
```

but it yielded a blank file.

Then I read the documentation of Tesserocr (python wrapper of Tesseract) and tried the following code

```
with PyTessBaseAPI() as api:
    api.SetImage(image)
    boxes = api.GetComponentImages(RIL.TEXTLINE, True)
    print 'Found {} textline image components.'.format(len(boxes))
    for i, (im, box, _, _) in enumerate(boxes):
        # im is a PIL image object
        # box is a dict with x, y, w and h keys
        api.SetRectangle(box['x'], box['y'], box['w'], box['h'])
        ocrResult = api.GetUTF8Text()
        conf = api.MeanTextConf()
        print (u"Box[{0}]: x={x}, y={y}, w={w}, h={h}, "
               "confidence: {1}, text: {2}").format(i, conf, ocrResult, **box)
```

and again it was not able to read any characters in the image.

My question is how should I go about solving this problem? ( I am not looking for a ready made code, but approach on how to go about solving this problem).

Would I need to train tesseract with sample images or can I just write code using existing libraries to somehow detect the co-ordinates of the truck and try to do OCR only within the boundaries of the truck?

Answer (score 0):

Tesseract expects document-only images, but you have non-document objects in your image. You need a sophisticated segmentation(then probably some image processing) process before feeding it to Tesseract-OCR.

Comment: Could you please elaborate more on the sophisticated segmentation part. How should I go about segmenting it and at what stage would it become ready to be fed to Tesseract?

Comment: -psm option of Tesseract is primitive compared to what you need. You need something similar to license plate detection process, i.e. locate text from non-text parts in an image. OpenCV and its communities might help.

Answer (score 0):

I have a three-step solution

- 1. Take the part of the image you want to recognize
- 2. Apply [Gaussian-blur](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d4/d13/tutorial_py_filtering.html)
- 3. Apply [simple-thresholding](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d7/d4d/tutorial_py_thresholding.html)

You can use a range to get the part of the image.

- For instance, if you select the

  - height range as: from `(int(h/4) + 40` to `int(h/2)-20)`
  - width range as: from `int(w/2)` to `int((w*3)/4)`

|  | Result |
| --- | --- |
| Take Part | [image] |
| Gaussian | [image] |
| Threshold | [image] |
| Pytesseract | CMA CGM |

Code:

---

```py
import cv2
import pytesseract

img = cv2.imread('YizU3.jpg')
gry = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
(h, w) = gry.shape[:2]
gry = gry[int(h/4) + 40:int(h/2)-20, int(w/2):int((w*3)/4)]
blr = cv2.GaussianBlur(gry, (3, 3), 0)
thr = cv2.threshold(gry, 128, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
txt = pytesseract.image_to_string(thr)
print(txt)
cv2.imshow("thr", thr)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```